# ImagenButton get Background()

Tags: java, android-studio

Quiero poder recuperar el valor del `background` de un `imagenbutton` para compararlo con una imagen en mi proyecto. Por ejemplo:

```
ImageButton ib1;ib1.getBackground()==R.drawable.foto
```

Esta opción no me funciona. Por favor si me dan una mano, cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Tendrías que declarar el objeto del tipo `Drawable`, por ejemplo: **`Drawable bg = ib1.getBackground();`**  y luego podrías comparar: **`if (bg==R.drawable.foto ) { //...código}`**

Comment: @A.Cedano no se puede comparar un drawable con el id(int) de un recurso. Tampoco se puede recupear el id de un recurso una vez que este se convirtio en drawable.

Comment: @ErickSilva ¿cuál sería entonces la forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion muy practica si necesitas saber la imagen de fondo de un boton, es usar el campo `tag` que tienen todas las vistas para guardar el id del recurso de la imagen `R.drawable.foto`.

Y cuando necesites compararlo comparas directamente el tag con el id de recurso que corresponda.

```
ImageButton ib1 = ...;
int tag = ib1.getTag();
int rid = R.drawable.foto;
if (tag == rid){
   //Es el boton correcto.
}
```

En el xml tu button deberia verse algo asi:

```
<ImageButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:tag="@drawable/image"
  android:background="@drawable/image" />
```